# Scrapy returns a different table than is indicated by developer tool

Tags: python, scrapy

Im trying to do some webscraping with scrapy for a project at uni. Essentially I need the data contained in the table on the following url:

https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?sort=omregnings_dato-d&kode=3&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&minsaledate=2004&maxsaledate=today&kom=461&type=Villa&gade=&searchTab=1&page=1

the problem is that when I run view(response) in the scrapy shell, the resulting page looks like a mess, and the corresponding table is entirely different. The table does contain similar data, but not from the area code or category (foreclosures) that I filtered in a prior step to obtain the URL.

When I navigate the developer tool in chrome I get selectors which are valid in Scrapy, only the data are those of the table that occurs in the view(response) webpage and not the table I get in my browser. I hope someone can help me with a solution, or at least point me to the problem as I'm rather new to webscraping.

For reference, this is my script which is just an adaption of the Scrapy tutorial

```
import scrapy
class BoligaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "boliga"

    #start_requests returns (via yield) a request object
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?sort=omregnings_dato-d&kode=3&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&minsaledate=2004&maxsaledate=today&kom=461&type=Villa&gade=&searchTab=1&page=1'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        filename = 'boliga.txt'
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:

            for i in range(1,50):
                row = response.css(f"table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(2) > span::text").get()
                if row is not None:
                    row = row[:-4]
                f.write(f"{row}\n")

        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I'm getting the accurate data from your code using scrapy default parse method.

```
import scrapy

class BoligaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "boliga"
    start_urls = ['https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?sort=omregnings_dato-d&kode=3&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&minsaledate=2004&maxsaledate=today&kom=461&type=Villa&gade=&searchTab=1&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):

        filename = 'boliga.txt'
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:

            for i in range(1, 50):
                row = response.css(
                    f"table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(2) > span::text").get()
                if row is not None:
                    row = row[:-4]
                f.write(f"{row}\n")

        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Comment: This does indeed work! Do you know why that is? Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Vahlgreen, your original code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need scrapy for such a small task, here is another (direct) approach.

```
from requests import get
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?sort=omregnings_dato-d&kode=3&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&minsaledate=2004&maxsaledate=today&kom=461&type=Villa&gade=&searchTab=1&page=1"

r = get(url)

html = r.content.decode()
soup = fromstring(html)
script = soup.xpath("//script[@id='boliga-app-state']/text()")[0]

jdata = loads(script.replace("&q;","\""))
table_json = ""

for ks in jdata.keys():
    if "page=" in ks:
        table_json = jdata[ks]['body']['results']
        break

print (table_json)
```

> Here is how first element ( table_json[0] ) looks like:

```
{'estateId': 0, 'address': 'Nøglens Kvarter 151', 'zipCode': 5220, 'price': 1350000, 'soldDate': '2021-06-14T22:00:00.000Z', 'propertyType': 1, 'saleType': 'Auktion', 'sqmPrice': 9060.402, 'rooms': 6, 'size': 149, 'buildYear': 1960, 'change': 0, 'guid': '4A79CADE-E914-4392-B6A0-3399006B7E15', 'latitude': 55.36823, 'longitude': 10.4514675, 'municipalityCode': 461, 'estateCode': 446086, 'city': 'Odense SØ', 'groupKey': None, 'canGetVR': True, 'bfEnr': 2651843}
```

Loop over other pages and their content in same manner!